# MYSQL/PHP/xHTTP - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm new here and am not sure if this problem belongs in this section or not.

I've built this website that interacts heavily with a MySQL database. All of my SQL statements are stored in a functions.php file. I simply include and call functions to execute a query. There are around **40+ functions** in total and when multiple people use the site for a short while or one user spams things, the webpage fails to load and **everyone** gets this **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** error.

I'm not sure what the problem is.

I have searched every corner of the web, there seems to be no one having the same exact problem. Other peoples problem with the same error message involves things that doesn't apply to my situation at all.

I've tried to narrow it down to specific functions,timing how often everything stops working (not consistent), but no luck.

Example mockup:

file1.php

```
$row_user = get_userinfo($conn, $username);
```

functions.php

```
**top of functions file**

$conn = mysqli_connect(w,x,y,z);

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

**function somewhere further down**

function get_userinfo($conn, $username){

    $person_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; 

    $person_result = mysqli_query($conn, $person_query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($person_result);
    return $row;
}
```

**I know there is much safer ways out there to talk to the database, prepared statements and all that, but thats not what im talking about right now**

I also have some xhttp requests in there, heres an example of one:
(this js function is called on document load)

function check_for_dueCallbacks(){

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data = this.responseText;
        push_callback(data);
        delay3(function(){
            check_for_dueCallbacks();
        }, 10000 );
    }else{
        delay3(function(){
            check_for_dueCallbacks();
        }, 40000 );
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", 'ajax/checkcallbacks.php', true);
xhttp.send();
```

}

This is by far the most mind boggling problem I have ever came across.

Thanks!

- Jake

Comment: This smells like an out-of-resources problem.  Is anything useful coming out of your web server's error log?

Comment: I've just checked, its completely empty

Comment: Also, these stats on the cpanel never really change or show any signs for concern ( http://i.imgur.com/RuG2iJP.png )

Comment: Either logrotate has popped your old logs out of cycle, or PHP is stuffing logs somewhere other than your web server's error log. But I guarantee zero errors ain't happening :-). See http://serverfault.com/q/574880 for more ideas.

Comment: It's possible that the server itself doesn't have resource problems, but that there's a PHP, FPM, or web server constraint (or something like DoS protection getting in your way here).  Things like these: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/apache-and-php-limits-and-timeouts .  Getting the error log would point you in a direction.

Comment: in the **error_log** I only see notices for empty $_GET[]'s which should be fine, the only other thing in there is a php session warning: http://pastebin.com/Jjj5MT7v

Comment: Then the throttling is happening earlier in the chain.  Are you using something like mod_evasive, a WAF, or iptables to rate-limit?  I'd tend to think it unlikely you're running out of TCP buckets, but you could also check https://www.frozentux.net/ipsysctl-tutorial/chunkyhtml/tcpvariables.html for the various mem and bucket settings (assuming Linux here).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that moving it to a better server helped. I ended up moving it all to a VPS and put 10 people on the system full blast.

***I just want to thank BJ Black for taking time out to help me. Nice guy! +1***

Works fine!